# Reading the power of a specific frequency using the Signal Hound USB_SA124B spectrum analyzer takes a long time, QCoDeS

Tags: python, performance

I use the Signal Hound USB_SA124B spectrum analyzer and to read the measurements into python code I use the QCoDeS framework(https://github.com/QCoDeS/Qcodes), which has drivers for the device.

QCoDeS provides a function that lets you read the power of a specific frequency(_get_power_at_freq(), alltough in the documentation they say there is a function called power(), but I can't find it).
The problem is that I need to read the frequency many times in a loop but using _get_power_at_freq() takes around 0.8-0.9 seconds and that adds up.
The thing is that the device can sweep a frequency range of about 100MHz in around a second(using the sweep function), so I think that using _get_power_at_freq() takes much longer than it should and maybe there's another faster way to do it, but I can't find any.
Anyone knows any way to improve it?
Thanks :)

Examples on the QCoDeS docs:
- https://qcodes.github.io/Qcodes/examples/driver_examples/Qcodes-example-with-Signal-Hound-USB-SA124B.html
- https://qcodes.github.io/Qcodes/examples/driver_examples/Qcodes-example-with-Signal-Hound-USB-SA124B-ParameterWithSetpoints.html

I tried using the sweep function and setting a small range but I didn't find a way to read the avarage power of the sweep.

This function sets up the device:

```
def setinstrument(freq, span):
    # Sets instrument drivers and connections
    path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Signal Hound\\Spike\\sa_api.dll'  # device's driver location
    mysa = qcodes.instrument_drivers.signal_hound.USB_SA124B.SignalHound_USB_SA124B('mysa', dll_path=path)

    print("-------------------------------------")
    print(mysa.get_idn())  # Prints instrument's details
    print("-------------------------------------")

    mysa.frequency(freq)  # Center of scanned region
    mysa.span(span)  # Width of scan region
    mysa.configure()

    return mysa
```

And I use:

```
mysa._get_power_at_freq()
```

I expect shorter time to read the frequency :/